# Flip Card doesn't focus and scroll with mouse wheel on both sides

Tags: css

I have a flip card with two long texts and when I am on the front sides it doesn't focus on scroll and doesn't scroll with mouse wheel or by finger when I am on cellphone.

I searched and used similar codes and ideas but none of them helped me. I thank you in advance if you could help me fix it.

my html:

```
<div class="flipCard"> 
  <div class="card" onclick="this.classList.toggle('flipped');"> 

    <div class="side front"><table><td>This is the front side of my flip card. It's a long text and the scroll doesn't focus and work with mouse wheel automatically.</td></table></div> 

    <div class="side back"><table><td>This is the back side of my flip card. It's a long text and the scroll focuses and works fine with mouse wheel.</td></table></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my css sorry that I couldn't summarize it more:

```
.flipCard {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  -ms-perspective: 800;
  -moz-perspective: 800;
  -o-perspective: 800;
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 50px auto;
}

.flipCard .card.flipped {
  transform:rotatey(-180deg);

}

.flipCard .card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.flipCard .card .side {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  backface-visibility: hidden;  /* W3C */
  overflow: auto;
}

.flipCard .card .back {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  transform:rotatey(-180deg);
}

.flipCard .card .front {
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #7030a0;
}

.flipCard .card .back {
  background-color: #dbb2f9;
  padding: 0.6em;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  text-align: center;
}

table{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
td{
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.front td{
  color: white;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 1.0em;
}
.back td{
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

I have my code here too:
https://codepen.io/teslapixela/pen/xxGdvoG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with touch and click events I think. On touch devices the on touch event is triggered before the click event.

I wrote an example here below (I've used jQuery to write the solution faster :)):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   if(window.matchMedia("(pointer: coarse)").matches) {
      // Touch device
      $('.card').on('touchstart touchmove', function(event) {     
           if (event.type == 'touchstart') {
              // Don't trigger the class toggle directly, user might be scrolling
              setTimeout(function() {
                if (event.type != 'touchmove') {
                   $(this).toggleClass('flipped'); 
                }
              }, 1);
           }
      });
   } else {  
      // Non touch device
      $('.card').on('click', function() {
           $(this).toggleClass('flipped'); 
      });
   }
});
```

```css
.flipCard {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  -ms-perspective: 800;
  -moz-perspective: 800;
  -o-perspective: 800;
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 50px auto;
}

.flipCard .card.flipped {
  transform:rotatey(-180deg);

}

.flipCard .card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.flipCard .card .side {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;  /* W3C */
  overflow: auto;
}

.flipCard .card .back {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  transform:rotatey(-180deg);
}

.flipCard .card .front {
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #7030a0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.flipCard .card .back {
  background-color: #dbb2f9;
  padding: 0.6em;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.flipCard .card.flipped .front {
   z-index: -1;
}

.flipCard .card.flipped .back {
  z-index: 1;
}

table{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
td{
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
}
.front td{
  color: white;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 1.0em;
}
.back td{
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flipCard"> 
  <div class="card"> 
    
    <div class="side front"><table><td>This is the front side of my flip card. It's a long text and the scroll doesn't focus and work with mouse wheel automatically.</td></table></div> 
    
    <div class="side back"><table><td>This is the back side of my flip card. It's a long text and the scroll focuses and works fine with mouse wheel.</td></table></div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the scrolling function doesn't still work for the front side.

Comment: @LordTesla Ok, I've added some z-indexes to fix that